# Ionic 4+ Capacitor Angular: How to write platform-specific ts-code for ios and android?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, capacitor

How to write platform-specific code in the ts-file? So code that is only valid for ios and code that is only valid for android? How can I determine whether the device runs ios or android as operating system?

I use Ionic 4+ with Capacitor and Angular.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Platform](https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/platform) to detect OS.

```
import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';

@Component({...})
export class MyPage {
  constructor(public platform: Platform) {
     if(platform.is('ios')){
        //ios logic
     }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So to write plugin specific TS code you need to **already have Capacitor plugin developed and it should expose methods etc** that you can use inside your TS code.

i think this is pretty compelling description of how the capacitor plugins ecosystem works

https://capacitor.ionicframework.com/docs/plugins/

Here is a detailed example from the article on how to create your own Android plugin:
https://capacitor.ionicframework.com/docs/plugins/android

Regarding OS the device runs one - Ionic has an in-built feature for that:
https://ionicframework.com/docs/building/cross-platform/#platform-detection

So using 'Platform' you could detect OS and perform OS specific actions
See Ionic's reference app's app.component.ts where it is in the app init method to detect when native splash screen etc plugins can be called:

https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-conference-app/blob/master/src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks for your efforts.

I have found what I was looking for.

https://capacitor.ionicframework.com/docs/apis/device

```
import { Plugins } from '@capacitor/core'; 
const { Device } = Plugins;
const info = await Device.getInfo();
console.log(info);

// Example output:
{
"diskFree": 12228108288,
"appVersion": "1.0.2", 
"appBuild": "123", 
"operatingSystem": "ios", 
"osVersion": "11.2", 
"platform": "ios", 
"memUsed": 93851648, 
"battery": -1, 
"diskTotal": 499054952448, 
"model": "iPhone", 
"manufacturer": "Apple", 
"uuid": "84AE7AA1-7000-4696-8A74-4FD588A4A5C7", 
"isVirtual":true 
}
```